# Удаление связи ManyToMany Symfony2 Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine2, twig, php, symfony2

**Здравствуйте**.

Возник вопрос следующего характера.
Имеется 2 таблицы Price и Suppliers, они связаны между собой связью ManyToMany.

Содержимое Suppliers.php

```
<?php
class Suppliers
/**
* @var Suppliers[]|ArrayCollection
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Price", inversedBy="suppliers", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
* @ORM\JoinTable(
*     name="PriceToSuppliers",
*     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="suppliers_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
*     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="price_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
* )
*/
public $price;
?>
    Содержимое Price.php    
<?php
class Price
{/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Suppliers", mappedBy="price", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 */
protected  $suppliers;
}
```

Содержимое шаблона Twig (урывок)

```
{% for price in price %}
<tr>
<td>{{ price.id }}</td>
<td>{{ price.name }}</td>
<td>{{ price.cost }}</td>
<td>{{ price.brand }}</td>
<td>{{ price.description }}</td>
<td>
{%for suppliers in price.supplier %}
{{ suppliers.supname }}
{% endfor %}
</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

ManyToMany использовал, потому что для одного Price может быть несколько Suppliers и наоборот. Сейчас вывод сделан, что выводится позиция с Price, и в колонке поставщик через цыкл выводятся все supplier.supname (наименования поставщика).

Так вот целью является реализация кнопки около поставщика, допустим, 'X' или 'Удалить', после нажатия на которую в таблице связующей "PriceToSuppliers" удалялась строка, которая связывает поставщика и позицию.

Answer (score 1):

Для решения данной задачи необходимо реализовать контроллер с методом для удаления, например:

```
class CatalogueController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{supplier}/{price}/delete", name="catalogue_delete")
     */
    public function removeAction(Supplier $supplier, Price $price)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $price->getSuppliers()->removeElement($supplier);
        $supplier->getPrice()->removeElement($price);

        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect(/* route_name */);
    }
}
```

И в цикле вывода поставщиков добавить ссылку, например:

```
{# catalogue/list.twig #}
{% for supplier in suppliers %}
    {{ supplier.name }}
    <a href="{{ path('catalogue_delete', {'supplier': supplier, 'price': price}) }}">удалить</a>
{% endfor %}
```

В идеале, только удаление должно происходить не по ссылке, а путем отправки формы.